# Assigning rbac role to a principal ID error "message":"Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated

Tags: azure-bicep

I have got a bicep module which does the following

1. creates user managed identities
2. creates a key vault
3. create a key in the vault in step 2
4. creates a sql server
5. configures the sql server to use a customer managed key using a key
   created

The first issue at the moment is that I have a module that assigns rbac roles, but this doesn't work for key vault.

**kvRBAC.bicep**

```
param serverName string
param keyVaultName string
param sqlServerIdentity string

resource keyVaultCryptoUser 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2022-04-01' existing = {
  name: 'Key Vault Crypto User'
}

resource cryptoKeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}
  // Assign new SQL Managed Identity the KV Crypto User role to the designated Key Vault.
  resource sqlServerKeyVaultRBAC 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
    name: guid(serverName, cryptoKeyVault.id, keyVaultCryptoUser.id)
    scope: cryptoKeyVault
    properties: {
      principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
      principalId: sqlServerIdentity
      roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments', '12338af0-0e69-4776-bea7-57ae8d297424')
    }
  }
```

**From main.bicep**

```
  module sqlServerKeyVaultRBAC2 './modules/kvRBAC.bicep' = {
    name: 'SetKeyVaultRBAC2'
    scope: resourceGroup(keyvault.keyVaultRG)
    params: {
      serverName: sql.serverName
      keyVaultName: keyvault.keyVaultName
      sqlServerIdentity: identityIDs[0].properties.principalId
    }
  }
```

I get the error

`"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"RoleAssignmentUpdateNotPermitted","message":"Tenant ID, application ID, principal ID, and scope are not allowed to be updated."}]}]}]}]}]}}`

the issue is that if I manually assign permissions from the portal, it works fine. I do want it all done via code, the issue is getting the principal ID in a way that is acceptable for bicep, the principal ID is also generated in code dynamically when ran for the first time.

The other issue is that I am not sure that a principal Id is being sent to the module as the ID is part of the `identityIDs` array, so running something like `identityIDs[0].properties.principalId`, bicep doesnt like this being passed to a module and I have no way of verifying that the principal ID is actually being returned in the first place.

trying to run `var x = identityIDs[0].properties.principalId` and passing `x` to the module hasn't worked either.

The second problem is with the creation of managed identities and trying to get the ID & principal ID back from the user managed identities.

create_mi.bicep

param managedIdentities array
param location string
param tagging object

```
resource create_managed_identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' = [ for name in managedIdentities: {
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tagging.tags
} ]
```

Passing an array to it

```
"mi_resources": [
    "mi-01",
    "mi-02",
    "mi-03",
    "mi-04"
]
```

Getting the ID/principal ID of the managed identities

```
resource identityIDs 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2023-01-31' existing = [for item in managedIdentities.mi_resources:{
  name: item
}
]
```

Referring to the principal ID's like this. `identityIDs[0].properties.principalId`

Just doesn't like it.

Comment: you r first erro is because you ve already created the role assignment, delete it let the bicep runs again